# How to add even numbers in a range using a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, sum, range

I have to create a program that gets a range from the user then adds each even number in the range and prints to screen. I am struggling to figure out how to add each number in the for loop. If the range is 5 to 10 the screen should print 24 as the answer. Below is my code.

```
//worksheet 4 - question 3
//asks user for a range. Adds even numbers in range and prints their sum.

import java.util.Scanner;

class P3LoopRange
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int initial, finalValue;

        System.out.print("Enter a start value: ");
        initial = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a second value: ");
        finalValue = input.nextInt();

        while (finalValue <= initial)
        {
            System.out.println("Second value must be larger than start value.");
            System.out.print("Enter a second value: ");
            finalValue = input.nextInt();
        }

        int range = finalValue - initial;

        int x = 0

        for (int i = initial; i <= finalValue; i++)
        {
            if (i%2==0)
            {
                int x = x+i;

            }
        }
        System.out.printf(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: dont declare x in the if-statement again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare twice the `x` local variable.
You cannot as it is not legal to have a duplicate local variable.
Besides, declaring it inside the loop makes it be overwritten at each iteration.
So, just declare it before the loop and it should be fine.

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = initial; i <= finalValue; i++)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        x = x + i;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but I still receive an error with exit code 1. Is my final print statement in the correct place?

Comment: It is at the correct place. Is it compile with `printf()` ? It should not. You should use `print()` rather than `printf()` to print an `int`.

Comment: I had somehow deleted a semi-colon. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change `int x = x+i;` to `x=x+i;`. Here you are re initializing `x` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is at: `int x = x+i;`

just remove `int` and your problem is solved